# Is it possible to split an elements viewport with javascript/html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, viewport

I would like to implement a split "viewport" and i'm wondering if it is possible in javascript/css/html.

What I mean is, a scroll area that scrolls similar to a book, where the content that overflows vertically on the left half is shown in continuation on the right. Similar to CSS columns but for a scroll area.

I've played with the idea quite a bit, and the only solution I can think of is to essentially duplicate the content in the left pane in the right pane, synchronize the scroll event, and offset the right area by the element height.

Here is a basic example I made:

https://amazing-thompson-651a40.netlify.app/

However, I'm wondering if there is a solution that doesn't require duplicating the DOM structure of the left pane onto the right. For example is it possible to access the view port/rendering engine directly and show what is "actually" overflowing the scrollarea, and offset it on the page?

Comment: Nice idea! The closest thing I can think of without duplicating elements is `-webkit-box-reflect` property. Or using html canvas.. I think canvas could actually a good solution for this.

Comment: Alternitevily you can split your content into pages. And on scroll transition between them with i.e odd on the left and even on the right. No duplicate content(also you never scroll through the same thing twice) and css grid can be used here...